# object defined error: iferror as string in vba

Tags: excel, vba

"Range("F" & i).Formula =" is throwing an object defined error message when usin g iferror in the string.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 16 To 194

If Range("O" & i) < 0 Then
    answer = MsgBox("Discounted. Are you sure?", vbYesNo)

    If answer = No Then
    Range("F" & i).Formula = "=iferror(VLOOKUP($B" & i & ",eac_equipment_list!$P:$S,2,FALSE),"")"

    End If

    If answer = vbYes Then

    Range("O" & i) = "0"

    End If          

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Thoughts? the code works fine when I simply use Vlookup with out the "iferror" portion.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
"=iferror(VLOOKUP($B" & i & ",eac_equipment_list!$P:$S,2,FALSE),"")"
```

should be

```
"=iferror(VLOOKUP($B" & i & ",eac_equipment_list!$P:$S,2,FALSE),"""")"
```

Embedded double-quotes in a string need to be doubled-up to escape them